# Path of getExternalStoragePublicDirectory on Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android, galaxy

In my app, I am creating files which are stored in the devices Downloads directory. All of my users are happy with this mechanism... except the ones using a Samsung Galaxy Note.

It's kind of hard to debug without owning such a device. Within my code, I am using

```
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "file01");
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        // show error
    } else {
        if (!newFile.mkdirs()) {
            // show error
        }
    }
```

to find the path for the target directory. On the Galaxy Note, the path returned is "/storage/sdcard0/Download". However, on the local file system directory is written in lowercase ("download") and the files created by my app do not obviously not exist on the local file directory. At least my users complain about this. I assume the problem to be related with the lowercase/uppercase difference in the path.

Does anybody have an idea why this works on all devices except the Galaxy Note?

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider adding an option in a settings menu to browse-select a custom destination - that should cover any variety of oddness.  But also bear in mind that MTP at least will not notice newly created files until you trigger a scan of them, or the device does that itself (such as on restart)

Comment: Thanks for this advise but I will not integrate any file browsers as long as the Android APIs do not offer a simple out-of-the-box mechanism for this task.

Comment: I don't believe Android's external storage is a *case sensitive* file system - at least it is *intended* to work like one which is not, and my tests on a 4.4.x Nexus device show *case preserving* but not *case sensitive* behavior.  So my suspicion remains with not having called the scanner - or perhaps your user is looking on a removable SD card secondary storage instead.

Answer (score 8):

There is no guarantee that the location returned by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` actually exists. Yours may be the first app that needs a particular one of those directories. Hence, it is your job to call `mkdirs()` on that location, on all devices, not just this one.

Beyond that, as to why somebody else (Samsung or another third-party app) is creating a lowercase `download` directory, the only way to determine "why" is to figure out who created that directory and then contact that developer. This is unlikely to be a worthwhile investment in time.

So long as you are calling `mkdirs()` to create `Download`, whatever other directories that may exist are not really your concern. If you wanted to detect possible collisions like this, and warn the user, you could do that, though I have no idea if that would be worthwhile.

Comment: OK, sorry. Forgot to mention that I am calling mkdirs(). I just edited my question and included the code which is used to create the files.