# cant find audiofile when recording sound

Tags: android, audio

My Problem is, that I capture audio by pressing the record button, but I can't see any audioFile in the specific path.

I capture sound, when I press the capture button:

```
 private void startRecord()
  {
 ImageButton soundStop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.soundstop);
        soundStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        //mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(sound);
        //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(soundFilePath);
        //mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(audioEncoder);
        //Log.d("hier ", "hier" + soundFilePath);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
          }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aufnahme gestartet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

When I press the Stop Recording Button the file should be saved in the specific path. I tried it with Directory Musik and Downloads, but I can't find any file there

```
 final OnClickListener soundRecordStop = new OnClickListener(){         

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            soundStop();
        }

    };

 public void soundStop(){

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String actualTime = sdf.format(time);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("soundformat", "format");

        int audioEncoder = sharedPreferences.getInt("audioEncoder", Property.getAudioEncoderInt());

        String dateiendung = ".aac";
        int sound = 6;

        if(name == "aac"){
            dateiendung = ".aac";
            sound = 6;

        } else if(name == "amr_nb"){
            dateiendung = ".3gp";
            sound = 3;
        }
        else if( name == "amr_wb"){
            dateiendung = ".3gp";
            sound = 4;
        }
        else if( name == "default" ){
            dateiendung = ".default";
            sound = 0;
        }
        else if( name == "mpeg"){
            dateiendung = ".mp4";
            sound = 2;
        }
        else if( name == "gpp" ){
            Log.d("in gpp", "in gpp");
            dateiendung = ".3gp";
            sound = 1;
        }

        soundFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        soundFilePath = soundFile.getAbsolutePath() + actualTime + dateiendung;

        Log.d("hier ", "hier1" + mediaRecorder);
        if(mediaRecorder != null){
            Log.d("hier ", "hier2" + mediaRecorder);
            try {
                //mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                //mediaRecorder  = null;
                Log.d("hier ", "hier4" + mediaRecorder);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(sound);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(soundFilePath);
        Log.d("hier ", "hier2");
        String pfad = soundFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aufnahme in " + pfad + " gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ImageButton soundStop = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.soundstop);
        soundStop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }
```

The path seems to be correct: pfad /storage/sdcard0/Download17.07.2014 11:55:58.aac

Thanks for the comment the missing File Separator wasn't intentionally.  I insert the missing Separator in Order to save the audio File in Downloads Directory.  But no File nevertheless

Please help me to find my file ;)

Comment: Since you left out a file separator after `soundFile.getAbsolutePath()` (maybe intentionally?), it looks like it's in the `/storage/sdcard0/` directory, with the filename `Download17.07.2014 11:55:58.aac`.

Comment: That doesn't help :( still can't find any file

Comment: Make sure you have this permission in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`. If that's not the problem, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484278/path-of-getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-on-samsung-galaxy-note