# Path delivered by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory does not work on Android 5.0

Tags: android

I want to store a picture in the photo directory of the device. I use

```
path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

After calling this method, on my S3 (Android 4.3), path contains "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures". When I try to create a file in this directory, it works. I use

```
File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, ".jpg", path);
```

for this.
I tested on a Galaxy S5 and on the emulator, both with Android 5.0. On emulator, path contains "/storage/sdcard/Pictures". When I try to create a file in it, I get a "java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)". My emulator has SD-card support enabled. The S5 had no SD-Card. Maybe this is the reason for the issue on the device. I use permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my manifest. I even tried to use file.mkdirs() to ensure the path exist. But this also not works.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484278/path-of-getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-on-samsung-galaxy-note

Comment: Does the path actually exist on the phone, the S5?

Comment: Milad, this describes my problem, but offers no answer.
Jared, unfortunately, I can not check it on this device, because its not my own.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - note that you can only verify such a path from another app like a file manager.  ADB will see the external storage mounted at a different location than where an app will see it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Your comment is irrelevant. You can simply try to use the Android API `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and check if the directory exists before you create a file and then create a file or you can specify your own location and do the same.

Comment: Since the poster already tried creating the directory and found that it failed, it really looked like you were recommending making an *independent* verification, and I was warning that one of the obvious ways of doing so would, due to an often-overlooked detail of Android implementation, give a misleading result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution:
In my AndroidManifest.xml, I used:

```
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

because of this information in the [doku](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html):

> For example, beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer
>   necessary for your app to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   permission when your app wants to write to its own
>   application-specific directories on external storage (the directories
>   provided by getExternalFilesDir()). However, the permission is
>   required for API level 18 and lower.

I misunderstood the fact that if I want to write to the picture directory, I still do need this permission, even in API > 19. So I removed this tag and it works.

Comment: Very helpful... its something that you could actually miss while reading this documentation.